# count of rows based on multiple conditions/partitions on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

DBFiddle Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2d7e9a4ddfdc8fb619a8dfc76d767950

Hi. I have one table called 'Model Versions' which has the fields and records as below.

| intent_id | intent_name | version | version_created_at | client | sentence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client1 | sentence_1 |
| 1 | a_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client1 | sentence_2 |
| 1 | a_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client1 | sentence_3 |
| 2 | b_intent | 2 | 2021-02-01 | es_client1 | sentence_1 |
| 2 | b_intent | 2 | 2021-02-01 | es_client1 | sentence_2 |
| 2 | b_intent | 2 | 2021-02-01 | es_client1 | sentence_3 |
| 3 | c_intent | 3 | 2021-03-01 | es_client1 | sentence_1 |
| 3 | c_intent | 3 | 2021-03-01 | es_client1 | sentence_2 |
| 4 | d_intent | 4 | 2021-04-01 | es_client1 | sentence_1 |
| 4 | d_intent | 4 | 2021-04-01 | es_client1 | sentence_2 |
| 5 | e_intent | 5 | 2021-05-01 | es_client1 | sentence_1 |
| 6 | g_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client2 | sentence_1 |
| 6 | g_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client2 | sentence_2 |
| 7 | h_intent | 2 | 2021-03-01 | es_client2 | sentence_1 |
| 7 | h_intent | 2 | 2021-03-01 | es_client2 | sentence_2 |
| 7 | h_intent | 2 | 2021-03-01 | es_client2 | sentence_3 |
| 8 | i_intent | 3 | 2021-04-01 | es_client2 | sentence_1 |
| 8 | i_intent | 3 | 2021-04-01 | es_client2 | sentence_2 |
| 9 | j_intent | 4 | 2021-05-01 | es_client2 | sentence_1 |
| 9 | j_intent | 4 | 2021-05-01 | es_client2 | sentence_2 |
| 10 | k_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client3 | sentence_1 |
| 10 | k_intent | 1 | 2021-01-01 | es_client3 | sentence_2 |
| 11 | k_intent | 2 | 2021-06-01 | es_client3 | sentence_1 |
| 11 | k_intent | 2 | 2021-06-01 | es_client3 | sentence_2 |
| 12 | k_intent | 3 | 2021-07-01 | es_client3 | sentence_1 |
| 12 | k_intent | 3 | 2021-07-01 | es_client3 | sentence_2 |
| 13 | k_intent | 4 | 2021-08-01 | es_client3 | sentence_1 |
| 13 | k_intent | 4 | 2021-08-01 | es_client3 | sentence_2 |
| 14 | k_intent | 5 | 2021-10-01 | es_client3 | sentence_1 |
| 14 | k_intent | 5 | 2021-10-01 | es_client3 | sentence_2 |

**Expected Output:**

I wanted to get the top 3 versions of each client along with their respective sentence count. My expected output looks like below:

| client | version | total_count_of_sentences_per_version | version_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| es_client1 | 5 | 1 | 2021-05-01 |
| es_client1 | 4 | 2 | 2021-04-01 |
| es_client1 | 3 | 2 | 2021-03-01 |
| es_client2 | 4 | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| es_client2 | 3 | 2 | 2021-04-01 |
| es_client2 | 2 | 3 | 2021-03-01 |
| es_client3 | 5 | 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| es_client3 | 4 | 2 | 2021-08-01 |
| es_client3 | 3 | 2 | 2021-06-01 |

I tried writing a query with multiple CTEs and Partition By's. But none worked out. Seeking your help to achieve this.

DBFiddle Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2d7e9a4ddfdc8fb619a8dfc76d767950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WITH main_tab
     AS (SELECT client,
                version,
                Count(*)
                  OVER (
                    partition BY client, version),
                Min(version_created_at)
                  OVER (
                    partition BY client, version),
                Dense_rank()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY client
                    ORDER BY version DESC) rn
         FROM   model_versions)
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM   main_tab m;
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which of the top 3 version you wish to fetch. I'll assume you want to retrieve the 3 latest versions, based on creation date.

My suggestion is to use a ROW_NUMBER() for each client in a windowed function, and to filter the top 3 rows.

For instance :

```
with cte as(
  select 
   client,
   version,
   version_created_at,
   count(Sentence) total_count_of_sentences_per_version,
   row_number() over(partition by client order by version_created_at desc) version_row_number
 from model_versions
 group by
   client,version,
   version_created_at
 )
select
  client,
  version,
  total_count_of_sentences_per_version,
  version_created_at
from cte
where version_row_number <=3
```

[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e79e966edaf14e0a28b43706b232f57b)